# How to find the all possible AdalException.ErrorCode string property values?

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-active-directory, adal

There is an exception type thrown when an error occurs during token acquisition when you try to acquire a token from Azure Active Directory.

The Exception is called *AdalException* [ms docs link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.adalexception?view=azure-dotnet)

I am after its property called *ErrorCode* [ms docs link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.adalexception.errorcode?view=azure-dotnet)

However they call it "error code" it's a string with possible values such as:

- "*temporarily_unavailable*"
- "*user_interaction_required*"
- and so forth...

From peeking the assembly it says

```
// Parameters:
//   errorCode:
//     The error code returned by the service or generated by client. This is the code
//     you can rely on for exception handling.
```

Could you point me to a direction where could I get all the possible values from? Or is it something whose value is only informational and unique or random?

What I'd like to do is have a different logic, so let's say if it's temporary unavailable, do a retry? If it's something else act accordingly...

Pseudo code:

```
catch (AdalException ex)
{                    
     if (ex.ErrorCode == "temporarily_unavailable")
     {
         retry = true;
         retryCount++;
         Thread.Sleep(3000);
     }
     else if (ex.ErrorCode == "foo")
     // rest of the code omitted for brevity...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Exceptions in ADAL.NET wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Exceptions-in-ADAL.NET) covers a lot of this detail.

The most important error/exception to handle is the `AdalSilentTokenAcquistionException` in which the tokens in your cache are no longer valid and need to be interactively refreshed.

The other exception I'd highly recommend building a robust error handler for `interaction_required` (in ADAL.NET this is an `AdalClaimsChallengeException` which can occur as a result of Conditional Access policies requiring extra authorization on `AcquireTokenSilent()` methods. In this case, if you can prompt the user, you simply need to repeat the failed request interactively. If you're app is unable to show interaction, then you can capture the `claims` parameter in the error and send it back to the client to re-authorize.

Comment: Cheers @Daniel! I mark yours as an answer, for you have not only answered, but also helped me to realise that my question was not that straight. The hints you wrote was really helpful to clear out things!

Comment: Awesome to hear! Let me know if you have any other questions, happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.adalerror?view=azure-dotnet

Under this link on the left hierarchy, hit the drop downs for AdalError>Fields and it should show all of the possibilities.